# Trying to find toggle button

Tags: angular2-forms, primeng

I am creating an Angular form using PrimeNG. The design has the below toggle button, but i can't see in the PrimeNG docs, does anyone know where i can get this?
[image]

Comment: Not sure I have uderstood your question. Are you looking for [InputSwitch](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/inputswitch) ?

Comment: Yeah i think InputSwitch is what i need to use, i 'll have to change the styling of it to match the design